# Display File Name and File Size in CWD in Node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, filesystems, stdout

I'm having trouble with this code. What I'm trying to accomplish is getting a list of the file names and sizes to print on the same line in STDOUT. Currently, I am getting a list of file names, and then a list of sizes, but I want the sizes to display along side the names. I am more familiar with how to do this in Python, and I'm surprised how hard this is to do in JavaScript. So if you could not only help me correct my code, but help me understand how the code is working in JS, then it would be much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let path = __dirname;

let files = fs.readdirSync(path);

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
  var fileStats = files[i];
  console.log("Start: " + fileStats);
  fs.stat(fileStats, function(err, stats){    
    console.log(stats.size);
  });
}
```

For comparison, this is what the code would look like in Python

```
import os
import os.path

path = os.getcwd()
contents = os.listdir(path)

print(path)
for file in contents:
  size = os.path.getsize(file)
  print("File: {0}, Size: {1} Bytes".format(file, size))
```

Thanks

Comment: Log the file name in the same callback that you log the stats. `.stat` is async so the callback isnt going to be called right after your file name log which is why you get the sizes printed after

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` is always going to create a new line. If you want it on the same line you have to do it in the same log.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let path = __dirname;

let files = fs.readdirSync(path);

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
  var fileStats = files[i];
  fs.stat(fileStats, function(err, stats){    
    console.log('Start:', fileStats, stats.size);
  });
}
```

You could use `process.stdout.write()`, which does not add the newline, but then your output would still be out of order.